# I don't understand the behavior of fonts in Xwindows

Tags: c, x11

Given the sample program:

```
/*
 * Study for multiple windows.
 */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    Window       w1, w2;
    XEvent       e;
    const char*  msg1 = "Hello, window 1";
    const char*  msg2 = "Hello, window 2";
    int          s1;
    int          s2;
    GC           gracxt1;
    GC           gracxt2;
    XFontStruct* font;
    XFontStruct* font2;
    Display* d1;
    Display* d2;
 
    d1 = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d1 == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);

    }
printf("d1: %p\n", d1);

    d2 = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d2 == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);

    }
printf("d2: %p\n", d2);
 
    s1 = DefaultScreen(d1);
    s2 = DefaultScreen(d1);
printf("s1: %d\n", s1);
printf("s2: %d\n", s2);
    gracxt1 = XDefaultGC(d1, s1);
#if 0
    gracxt2 = XDefaultGC(d2, s2);
#else
    gracxt2 = XDefaultGC(d1, s2);
#endif

    font = XLoadQueryFont(d1,
        "-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-200-200-m-0-iso8859-1");
    if (!font) {

        fprintf(stderr, "*** No font ***\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    XSetFont(d1, gracxt1, font->fid);

    font2 = XLoadQueryFont(d1,
            "-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-400-400-m-0-iso8859-1");
    if (!font2) {

        fprintf(stderr, "*** No font ***\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    XSetFont(d1, gracxt2, font2->fid);

    w1 = XCreateSimpleWindow(d1, RootWindow(d1, s1), 10, 10, 640, 480, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d1, s1), WhitePixel(d1, s1));
    XSelectInput(d1, w1, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d1, w1);

    w2 = XCreateSimpleWindow(d1, RootWindow(d1, s1), 10, 10, 640, 480, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d1, s2), WhitePixel(d1, s2));
    XSelectInput(d1, w2, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d1, w2);

    while (1) {

        XNextEvent(d1, &e);
        if (e.type == Expose) {

            if (e.xany.window == w1) XDrawString(d1, e.xany.window, gracxt1, 10, 50, msg1, strlen(msg1));
            else XDrawString(d1, e.xany.window, gracxt2, 10, 50, msg2, strlen(msg2));

        }
        if (e.type == KeyPress) break; /* exit on any key */

    }

    XCloseDisplay(d1);
    XCloseDisplay(d2);

    return 0;

}
```

It sets up two windows, and selects two different fonts, one for each window, and prints. My understanding of XWindows is that the font is selected into the graphics context, the GC. However, I get two different behaviors depending on which Display* is used:

#if 1

[image]
IE, each window with a different size font, or:

#if 0

[image]

I would think, and the documentation strongly implies, that the font is selected to the context gracxt1 or gracxt2 by the XSetFont() call. Thus I started this example with two GCs, but one Display* and one screen select. However, I don't get the behavior of font select per window until I give each window its own Display*.

The prints show:

d1: 0x55a5694692a0
d2: 0x55a569477170
s1: 0
s2: 0

For both, distinct Display* but same screen indexes. So where is the font select for the window stored? The Display*?

The documentation says "the font is selected to the GC, and the display just specifies the connection to the X server".

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

I printed the GContext numbers for each of gracxt1 and gracxt2:

#if 1 (working case)

```
d1: 0x55b4ae3d82a0
d2: 0x55b4ae3e6170
s1: 0
s2: 0
GCContext 1: 69206016
GCContext 2: 71303168
```

#if 0 (failing case)

```
d1: 0x55b4149672a0
d2: 0x55b414975170
s1: 0
s2: 0
GCContext 1: 69206016
GCContext 2: 69206016
```

The program refactored to function correctly:

```
/*
 * Study for multiple windows.
 */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    Window       w1, w2;
    GC           gracxt1, gracxt2;
    XEvent       e;
    const char*  msg1 = "Hello, window 1";
    const char*  msg2 = "Hello, window 2";
    int          s;
    XFontStruct* font;
    Display* d;
 
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);

    }
 
    s = DefaultScreen(d);
    s = DefaultScreen(d);

    w1 = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 640, 480, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w1, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w1);
    gracxt1 = XCreateGC(d, w1, 0, NULL);

    w2 = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 640, 480, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w2, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w2);
    gracxt2 = XCreateGC(d, w2, 0, NULL);

    font = XLoadQueryFont(d,
        "-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-200-200-m-0-iso8859-1");
    if (!font) {

        fprintf(stderr, "*** No font ***\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    XSetFont(d, gracxt1, font->fid);

    font = XLoadQueryFont(d,
            "-bitstream-courier 10 pitch-bold-r-normal--0-0-400-400-m-0-iso8859-1");
    if (!font) {

        fprintf(stderr, "*** No font ***\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    XSetFont(d, gracxt2, font->fid);

    while (1) {

        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        if (e.type == Expose) {

            if (e.xany.window == w1) XDrawString(d, e.xany.window, gracxt1, 10, 50, msg1, strlen(msg1));
            else XDrawString(d, e.xany.window, gracxt2, 10, 50, msg2, strlen(msg2));

        }
        if (e.type == KeyPress) break; /* exit on any key */

    }

    XCloseDisplay(d);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You initialize both screen indices (`s1` and `s2`) as `DefaultScreen(d1)`, so they're bound to be the same. But even if you initialize them off different displays, they'll be the same because screen indices are simple integers that start from zero.

Comment: It might be more interesting to print the `GContext` of each `GC`, which you can get using `XGContextFromGC`.

Comment: I see (said the blind man), so the GContext is just a logical number for the context data, so my XDefaultGC just pointed both to the same context data, and then I modified it twice with different fonts.

Comment: That is my belief, but it is only correct if you have labeled your screen shots backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is part of the graphics context. Every graphics context has its own independent font setting.

I think your post has reversed the behaviors of the `#if 0` and `#if 1` cases. If so, then the behaviors you describe make perfect sense.

[`XOpenDisplay` creates one graphics context per screen after connecting to the server.](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/5faa8dc0b364f55f19034c370436074646d9ad54/src/OpenDis.c#L513-L515) So `d1` has a graphic context for screen 0, and `d2` has a separate graphics context for screen 0. Therefore:

- In both cases, `gracxt1` uses the graphics context of `d1` screen 0.
- In the `#if 0` case, `gracxt2` uses the graphics context of `d2` screen 0, which is **separate from** `gracxt1`. You set each GC's font to a different value. This is the behavior we see in your first screen shot: the two GCs have separate fonts.
- In the `#if 1` case, `gracxt2` uses the graphics context of `d1` screen 0, which is **the same as** `gracxt1`. When you set `gracxt2`'s font, you are **also** setting `gracxt1`'s font, overriding the earlier setting (because they are the same GC). This is the behavior we see in your second screen shot.

Comment: Makes sense. I need a distinct graphics context for each window. Thinking about how to do that (a better way to do that). I'll post a refactor. I think you are underpaid for this :-)

Comment: Small nit: #if 0 is a "no execute", meaning the statement enclosed by it are NOT executed. It then falls to the #else. So #if 0 uses d1, and #if 1 uses d2, so the screenshots are correct.

Comment: oh ha ha indeed